# In amcharts' stacked column chart, how do I display all the values of a particular column in tooltip?

Tags: javascript, amcharts

In amcharts stacked column chart,
Through the default method, when I hover over a particular section in a column, I see tooltip for that section only.

If I want to display all the values of a column wherever I hover on that column, how is that possible?
**Edit:**

i.e in this example,
 [amcharts.com/demos/100-stacked-column-chart/?theme=spiritedaway](https://amcharts.com/demos/100-stacked-column-chart/?theme=spiritedaway)

There are 3 sections for column "One", when I hover on the topmost section it says "series 3: 33.33%". I want it to display "series 1: 11.11% series 2: 55.56% series 3: 33.33%" all together in the tooltip. Is that possible?

P.S: I am not a developer but a UI designer, my team is saying it is not possible, but by looking at the code, I feel like it is possible

Comment: can you post the code that you have tried

Comment: @DILEEPTHOMAS
I am a designer not a developer, the development team is saying it is not possible. The question is with respect to this:
https://www.amcharts.com/demos/100-stacked-column-chart/?theme=spiritedaway

In the tooltip, I want to show all data of a particular column.

Comment: you need to show the total on the top of each stacked bar or up to where ever you hover you need to get the total

Comment: so on the first section where ever you hover you need to get as "series 1: 11.11% series 2: 55.56% series 3: 33.33%". Is it

Comment: @DILEEPTHOMAS yes yes..you got it! As in wherever I click on the first column, irrespective of the section, it should display all 3.

Answer (score 1):

Correct me if I am wrong, but currently there is no simple way to display all series' information in a single tooltip on an x axis level.

I have tried to override the `getTooltipText` adapter in `xAxis`, and I was able to access the raw data:

```
...,
xAxes: [{
    type: "CategoryAxis",
    adapter: {
        getTooltipText: function(text, target, key) {
            let dataItem = target.dataItemsByCategory.getKey(text),
                data = dataItem.dataContext;

            // Here you can access the raw data
            // i.e., data.value1, data.value2, etc

            return text;
        }
    }
}],
...
```

But then I had to recalculate their percentages every single time, and I couldn't put HTML on the return text (there is no getTooltipHTML adapter).

#### Display values along with Legend

I ended up displaying the series' values along with their legends instead. And there is a documented way to do so: https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/legend/#Interacting_with_cursor

You just need to define the legend settings on each series, and turn on the legend as well as the cursor:

```
...,
series: [{
    type: "ColumnSeries",
    ...,
    legendSettings: {
        valueText: "---%",
        legendSettings: "[bold]{valueY.totalPercent.formatNumber('#.00')}%"
    },
    ...
}],
...,
legend: {},
cursor: {
    lineX: {
        disabled: true
    },
    lineY: {
        disabled: true
    }
},
...
```

[image]

**demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/davidliang2008/582snbwo/57/

Comment: Thanks David. I wish they enroll this feature in future. It is very helpful for getting a comparative view in a single column.

Comment: @Arshi: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/53790136/2410655 for workarounds. I personally like displaying data along with legends instead of tooltips as there is only so little you can do with tooltips.