# Why is my AmChart XYChart only showing a single tooltip for multiple series?

Tags: tooltip, amcharts

I'm using AmCharts v4 to create an XYChart with 3 series. When each series is created, I assign a tooltip:

```
series.tooltipText = "{name}: [bold]{valueY}[/]";
```

However, the chart ends up displaying only a single tooltip (Temperature: -50).

[image: Single tooltip, multiple series]

There are many questions on StackOverflow about the opposite problem: users seeing multiple tooltips displayed by default, when they want to see a single combined tool-tip. For example, I want my chart to look like the one in this question:

[Amcharts 4, xychart, limiting the number of tooltips and combining infos in one tooltip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53642610/amcharts-4-xychart-limiting-the-number-of-tooltips-and-combining-infos-in-one)

How is it possible that I have created 3 series, each is displayed correctly, each has a tooltip assigned, but I only see one tooltip when hovering?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, the explanation is: I was creating a chart and pushing my data directly to chart.data.

It turns out that I need to push the series-specific datapoints to series.data individually for each series. Then I get a separate tool-tip for each series. This concept is explained here:

https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/series/

Comment: Im facing the same issue, Can you post the code of your solution?

Comment: @NestorPerez sorry, it was for a previous job so it's proprietary. Are you doing what I suggest in this post? Creating the chart first, and pushing data-points individually?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I solve it by adding

```
widget.chart.series.getIndex(j).data = datas;
```

instead of

```
widget.chart.data = datas;
```

Answer (score 0):

I find a solution maybe it helps was written in Angular framework. I wrote a general function which  is uploading the chart data one by one.

```
private uploadChartData(readings: Reading[], dataFieldX: string, dataFieldY: string): void {
    const seriesIndex: number = this.findSeriesIndex(dataFieldY);
    for (const reading of readings) {
        const chartData = {
            [dataFieldX]: reading.timeStamp,
            [dataFieldY]: reading.value
        };
        this.addOneChartData(chartData, seriesIndex);
    }
}

private findSeriesIndex(seriesName: string): number {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.chart.series.values.length; i++) {
        if (this.chart.series.values[i].dataFields.valueY === seriesName) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

private addOneChartData(chartData: any, seriesIndex: number): void {
    this.chart.addData(chartData);
    this.chart.series.getIndex(seriesIndex).addData(chartData);
}
```